# Fingerspelling and handedness in ASL

Tags: asl

The fingerspelling sign for "L" actually looks like a written "L" when it is made with palm out and with the right hand.

If a signer's dominant hand is their left one, how should they make this sign -

- with palm out, so that it look likes a backward "L", or
- with palm in, so that it looks like an "L"?

Similarly, how should the sign for "ILY" be made by a left-handed signer?

Comment: This should be in language learning, not here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Backward L](https://www.signingsavvy.com/blog/377/Does+it+matter+which+hand+I+sign+with%3F+Using+Your+Dominant+Hand+When+Signing). "Mirror mode" is a [natural part](https://www.handspeak.com/learn/5/) of a left-handed 'sign voice', with a few exceptions for signs with external referents (i.e. pointing or referring to fixed points in the space common to both signers) in the grammar of ASL.

This goes further: the [distinction between dominant and non-dominant hand](https://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/pages-layout/rightorlefthand.htm) is preserved in ASL, maintaining the "mirror mode".